# Cannot access function signature inside forEach

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following code and I want to access inside the `forEach` (where is the debugger) the `configEntry` function signature, is it possible?

```
_update: function(FileContent, configEntry) {
    var self = this;
    if (configEntry.elementId != null) {
        configEntry.elementId.forEach(function(elementEntry) {
            debugger;

        });

    }
```

The `configEntry` is an object.

In debug mode the `ConfigEntry` is `null`

Comment: why not? I guess the problem is that chrome optimizes code and that var is not accessible if there is no usage of it, like when you have only `debugger`, try to make it like `configEntry[something]; debugger` and re-check again

Comment: that should work, just try to log it in console and see

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/z9qq6L2j/1/?

Comment: @llamerr - yes You are write it appear that chrome do this trick, Thanks!

Comment: @ArunPJohny - Thanks it seems that the problem is coming from the debugger itself , the console solve this issue. THanks!